# How can I convert Ros images to stream?

Tags: python, stream, webrtc, ros, janus

I'm trying to convert ROS Image to stream(not video format eg.mp4) and send it to the Janus webrtc server with python. The reason why I need stream is the params of 'MediaPlayer' in aiortc module which helps communicate with Janus(webrtc) server, can only receive video format and stream format(eg. /dev/video0) and I should not save it as video format.

So what I am thinking now is converting ros image to a gstreamer.
How can I convert it? or is there any good solution?

Answer (score 0):

try use web_video_server or jpeg_streamer

Comment: This seems like a good direction, but more information about how those two are  potential solutions to the problem would go a long way to making this answer understandable and usable to a broader audience with a similar problem.